# Get output of a command on an ssh session using AppleScript

Tags: terminal, applescript, ssh, iterm

I'm connecting to an `ssh` session with AppleScript as follows:

```
tell application "iTerm2"
  tell current window
   create tab with default profile
  end tell

  tell first session of current tab of current window
    split horizontally with default profile
    split vertically with default profile
    write text "ssh username@server"
    write text "ls" -- I need to get the output of command
  end tell
end tell
```

How can I get the output of the command on the remote machine?

The following didn't work : `set x to  write text "ls"`

Comment: @user3439894 done , I've updated the code

Comment: @user3439894 I'm not able to compile , please note I have multiple panes in same window , can you please show code sample ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding, e.g.,:

```
delay 1
set foo to contents
```

After:

```
write text "ls" -- I need to get the output of command
```

In the *code* of the OP, e.g.,:

```
tell application "iTerm"
    tell current window
        create tab with default profile
    end tell
    
    tell first session of current tab of current window
        split horizontally with default profile
        split vertically with default profile
        -- write text "ssh username@server"
        write text "ls" -- I need to get the output of command
        delay 1
        set foo to contents
    end tell
end tell
```

Gets the *contents* of the *target* in which one could then parse `foo` to get the information sought.

---

Note that while `-- write text "ssh username@server"` is commented out, nonetheless, I did test it with a valid `ssh` login and it did return the expected results in the `contents`.

Also a `delay` was absolutely necessary and the *value* of the `delay` may need to be adjusted as the condition warrants.

Comment: Works, but there should be no reason to actually need the GUI terminal.

Comment: that worked very well :)

Answer (score 1):

A better way to do what you want:

```
-- this ssh assumes that public-key authentication is set up to the server

set the_output to do shell script "ssh name_or_ip_of_server ls"

-- the_output contans the result of the ls
```

Doing what you were trying to do would depend on the terminal capturing the entire `ls` in the scrollback buffer and you being able to retrieve it back from the buffer.  You don't need the GUI terminal (whether Terminal/iTerm) in order to do what you asked.

Comment: Thank you , I tried this before but I need the interactive session. I don't want to send each command with ssh.

Comment: Why not?  There's no reason not to simply send commands.  Group commands as you need to.  GUI scripting is inherently brittle, note the comment in the other answer about necessary delay.